# Windows 10 possible bug for Gigabit ISP connections for main network device?

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking

I am super frustrated with this topic as my main problem is that I have a Gigabit connection and is not working as expected on Windows 10 normal boot. I am starting to think that this is a new recent bug but I was not able to find anything related to this... FYI I sometimes reach 1010 Mbps, so my ISP is not the problem and you will see why.

So the issue is, as I stated, that my Gigabit network does not reach even 400 Mbps on my Windows 10, current hardware and software info:

- OS: Windows 10 Pro
- Version: 20H2
- Build: 19042.630
- CPU: i9 9900x
- OS installed on a Samsung NVMe M2 960 PRO (512 Gb)
- Motherboard: Asus ROG x299 e-gaming (it can handle 1 Gbps and it comes with integrated AC WiFi)
- My router: Asus ROG GT-AC5300

Things I have tried (even all together):

- Shutting everything down on my network
- Shutting everything down on my PC (processes)
- Doing a fresh install (format 100%)
- Changing network cable from CAT5 to CAT6
- Connect directly to Modem
- I tried changing Bandwidth Reserve on Policy Manager
- I tried the CMD auto tuning thing
- I tried turning off Automatic Proxy
- I tried turning off IPv6
- I tried turning off Large packets or something like that
- I think more things but it will not matter you will see why
- I do not have an antivirus apart of Windows Defender
- My Firewall is off

Things I have tried **that seems to show different results on the same OS and PC** (and this is why I think it is a new Windows 10 bug):

- I also have dual boot (Ubuntu 18.04 + Ubuntu 20.04) and **both downloads mostly everything and instantly at 110 Mb/s (950 mbps)**
- I have tried using my Wifi connection (I have previously said my motherboard has a Wifi connection too) and it starts downloading **same thing at higher speeds**, ethernet uses approximately 300 mbps, and Wifi (on status says 840 Mbps connection), I get download speeds of 600 Mbps - 500 Mbps when downloading **same thing**.
- I boot my windows on **safe boot with network** and I **instantly have 950 mbps on my downloads** but on normal boot **NOT**, only 300 mbps
- I have tried a fresh install using latest windows ISO tool, and when I started using it (**without installing any software**), I tried downloading something (that I know will get me max speed) and I got same 300 mbps speed, changed to **safe boot with network** again and I got 950 Mbps again...

So, this is clearly not a configuration thing nor a driver problem as I have the latest driver from the motherboard support page and makes no difference on normal boot but makes a difference on safe boot...

I am 99% sure this is a bug or something like that because when I turn off my ethernet (from network panel) and starts using Wifi, the speeds goes instantly up, but if I go back to Ethernet, I get this problem (on normal boot) again... As I mentioned before, I also tried changing the Reserve bandwidth on the Policy manager, and it made no difference...

**I remember starting to close mostly all applications like Steam, Spotify, even software that uses 0 internet like Nvidia Broadcast, iCUE (for my lights and AIO block) and after closing some of them (because of amount, not specific apps) it started using 950 Mbps again... so this is clearly a Windows 10 bug...**

Another info I can give is that (any browser) gives 750 Mbps more or less for download using http://speedtest.net but if I go to the Windows 10 app (that you can find on the store) I get 320 - 300 mbps... and if I download (games) with Uplay I get something between 500 mbps (60 Mb/s) but Steam and other apps cannot use more than 400 - 300 mbps, **I have to do the wired to wifi change and start using wifi on normal boot to use at least 500 to 600 mbps (my motherboard's wifi cannot handle more)**.

What else can I try ? Again, remember that on **safe boot with network** or **using other OS** or **changing main connection from wired (1 gbps) to wifi (840 mbps)** gives me full speed or 3/4 of it...

Comment: Hard to know. If I plug my Laptop into Ethernet, I get top speed sync transfers between Desktop (wired) and Laptop through a fast Cisco router. Try updating BIOS.  Try Windows on its own disk (not part of dual boot). Both machines 20H2 most recent update. Desktop gets full speed with ISP (slower of course than internal LAN speeds)

Comment: @John dual boot are on separate disks, windows is on the mentioned NVMe and ubuntu on other SSD and I am not talking about PCs transfers, I am talking about Internet speeds

Comment: As I said, I get top Internet Speeds with my Wired connection.

Comment: Which application exactly?

Comment: @Ramhound any app

Comment: @John so ? If you search about this issue, there are a lot of users trying to explain this and none of them were able to solve it, I was lucky to find out that changing to another network device or going safe boot will give me full speed... they did not say anything about that... so you are lucky that your internet speed is 1 Gbps and do not suffer from this...

Comment: I have not seen an issue with Clients that wired connection does not provide full ISP speed. That is less than LAN speed of course. As I said "hard to know"

Comment: I just did here (home office) side by side comparison of ISP Speed:  One wired computer, Two wireless computers - all three report essentially the same ISP speed. That is what I have seen elsewhere also.